# Forward declration using Template template parameters

Tags: c++, templates

For the life of me I cannot get this forward declaration to compile. Everything looks syntactically correct, but I get a type/value mismatch error.

```
namespace C {
   template <class TBinaryPredicate> class E;
}

template< template<typename> class TField> class CF;

using CE_Less = C::E<std::less<Date>>;
using CF_Less = CF<CE_Less>;  <==== COMPILER NOT HAPPY HERE
```

Compiler Error:

> error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template class TField> class CF'

What is the proper way to declare this template alias?

Comment: `CF` needs a template as a parameter, but `CE_Less` isn't a template; it's a concrete class (obtained by instantiating a template). Can you explain what you're trying to do?

Comment: Nothing looks syntactically correct. What's giving you that impression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CF` expects a template : `CE_Less` is not a template alias, it's a simple alias, you probably meant to use a template alias :

```
template<class T>
using CE_Less = C::E<std::less<T>>;

using CF_Less = CF< CE_Less >;
```